# entity recognition and disambiguation api

Tags: java, wordnet, named-entity-recognition, word-sense-disambiguation, wsd

I am looking for entity recognition and disambiguation API or library. I found JIGSAW algorithm which does WSD but at individual word level, so it can not recognize "financial institution" or "interest rate" as one unit, even that these units can be found in wordnet and have synsets (ex. see "financial institution in wordnet).

However, I found BabelNet, which has a graphical web interface which does exactly that. However, it does not provide that functionality in its current API v.3

Are you aware of an API or library that provides such functionality?
I mean to recognize "financial institution" or "interest rate" as one unit, and to do sense disambiguation on that basis!?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried running Stanford's NER over the text first? Most algorithms should be able to deal with `financial_institution` as the input rather than `financial institution` (underscore)

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is a bit old but for whoever gets here looking for a similar answer.

You can now use Babelfy. It's a disambiguation application with an API and you can perform disambiguation to a whole text (not just words) and in several languages.

[Babelfy](http://babelfy.org/)